# Python split() function clarification

Tags: python, list, split

I'm very new to Python and i'm just trying to wrap my head around a few things.

I'm given a bunch of txt files to open, which contain thousands of words, all seperated by whitespace, which i believe I have covered that in my code below.. But im just wondering how to then break those lines down into blocks of 3 or some int input by a user?

From `['perfect', 'dealing', 'crave', 'stirring', 'expedition', 'alexandria', 'vanish', 'dealing', 'crave']`

To `[['perfect', 'dealing', 'crave'], ['stirring', 'expedition', 'alexandria'],['vanish', 'dealing', 'crave']]`

or even back into list formation

```
a
b
c
```

TIA

```
word_list=[]
filename = "filename.txt"
with open(filename,"r") as file_object:
    for line in file_object:
        word_list=line.split()
        print(word_list)
    return(word_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `grouper` construct from the itertools recipes:

```
def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
```

Your code is then:

```
word_list = []
n = 3
filename = "filename.txt"
with open(filename, "r") as file_object:
    for line in file_object:
        word_list.append(grouper(line.split(), n))
return word_list
```

Comment: I didn't know that existed! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `for i in range(0, len(word_list), 3)` to iterate over the list in gaps of 3 and use the index to slice the original list

```
new_list = [word_list[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(word_list), 3)]
# [['perfect', 'dealing', 'crave'], ['stirring', 'expedition', 'alexandria'], ['vanish', 'dealing', 'crave']]
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not updating `word_list` but rather over writing its value, it should be something like.

```
word_list=[]
filename = "filename.txt"
with open(filename,"r") as file_object:
    for line in file_object:
        word_list.append(line.split()) # notice this
        print(word_list)
    return(word_list)

sub_list_size = 3; # take from user input or as needed
output = [word_list[i: i+sub_list_size] for i in range(0, len(word_list), sub_list_size)]
print(output)
```

Comment: ahhh that makes more sense. I wasn't appending as I thought it just needed to be overwritten! Big help, thanks